# elasticsearch in json string (and / or )

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am new to AWS elasticsearch but need to create queries to search the follow data with different criteria.

1. search_metadata (json string with key/value pair) - `"{\"number\":\"111\"; \"area\":\"central\"; "\code\":\"1111\"; \"type\":\"internal\"}"`
2. category - `"statement" or "bill" or "email"`
3. datetime - `"2019-05-04T00:00:00" or "2019-07-16T00:01:00"`
4. flag - `"good" or "bad"`

I need to construct query to do the following

1. AND or OR condition in search_metadata field (JSON string) -> not sure how to do it.
2. along with AND condition for category, datetime range and flag. -> Do I need to use muliti-match for flag and category ?

   ```
      "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
         {
           "match_phrase": {
             "search_metadata": "number 111"  --> not sure about AND or OR with "area" and others          
           }
         },     
        {
         "range": {
           "datetime": {
             "gte": "2019-05-04T00:00:00Z",
             "lte": "2019-07-16T00:01:00Z"
           }
          }
        }  
        ]
       }
      }
     }
   ```

Comment: can't you simply use the rest-high level java client for querying ES?

Comment: Will do that next. Also, I figured out how to do the above using" bool" (should) again within "must" to get my result.

Comment: any luck to make it work?